# Floatation device for dogs with weak back/rear

Tags: dogs, swimming

Our aging Border Collie *really* enjoys swimming. But his rear-end is getting weak, with muscle atrophy in the rear legs. So his rear-end is sinking as he cannot kick-stroke efficiently with the back feet.

He has a flotation device, but the floating foam is (a) above his back (not really in the water), and (b) only on the chest rather than the rear-end where he needs a lift.

Is there any kind of flotation device for the back-half of the dog, to lift the rear-end without impairing swimming?

Comment: Could you add a picture of the floating device you're currently using? A quick search shows that most commercial devices concentrate on the chest area, but maybe there's an option to alter yours.

Comment: Whatever floatation device you get, since it is a physically weakening dog, I'd only take in in water in places where a rescue will be easy.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find something only for the rear legs. But maybe you could make your own:

[image: dog harness for trnsportation via helicopter or similar]

If you would use this kind of [harness](https://www.alpinsport-basis.de/Singing-Rock-Hundetransportgurt-Laika), you could add some floating material only at the rear. Additional you would have a handle to hold your dog in case of emergency.